Converting SVG with external images to PNG using Sharp in Node
I am trying to convert an SVG to PNG using Sharp in NodeJs. I have the following code
export const convertSvgToPng = async (svgCode: string) => {
  try {
    // Convert the SVG code to a PNG buffer
    const pngBuffer = await embedImagesInSvg(svgCode);

    return pngBuffer;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error converting SVG to PNG:`, error);
  }
};

// Utility function to download image and convert to Base64
async function fetchImageAsBase64(url: string) {
  const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
  // Compress the image using sharp
  const image = sharp(response.data);

  const compressedImageBuffer = await image.png({ compressionLevel: 9 }).toBuffer();
  const base64Image = compressedImageBuffer.toString('base64');
  const mimeType = response.headers['content-type'];
  return `data:${mimeType};base64,${base64Image}`;
}


// Function to modify SVG by embedding multiple base64 images
async function embedImagesInSvg(svgCode: string) {
  // let svgContent = fs.readFileSync(svgFilePath, 'utf8');

  // Regex to match all xlink:href occurrences
  const regex = /xlink:href="([^"]+)"/g;
  let match;
  const imagePromises = [];

  // Collect all image URLs
  while ((match = regex.exec(svgCode)) !== null) {
    const imageUrl = match[1];
    imagePromises.push(fetchImageAsBase64(imageUrl));
  }

  try {
    // Wait for all images to be fetched and converted to base64
    const base64Images = await Promise.all(imagePromises);

    // Replace each xlink:href with the base64-encoded image
    svgCode = svgCode.replace(regex, () => {
      const base64Image = base64Images.shift();
      return `xlink:href="${base64Image}"`;
    });

    // Convert the modified SVG to PNG using sharp
    return sharp(Buffer.from(svgCode)).png().toBuffer();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching one or more external images:', error);
  }
}

I am using the above code to convert the external image links to base64 before replacing them in the SVG. This is because Sharp doesn't convert external links to PNG.
The problem is that the base64 strings are too long so Sharp throws the following error
Error converting SVG to PNG: Error: Input buffer has corrupt header: glib: XML parse error: fatal error code=2 (1) in (null):1:10003752: Memory allocation failed : Huge input lookup

I have even tried image compression but that didn't work

I don't think this is actually a memory issue, FWIW. What does fetchImageAsBase64 actually do? Yes, it returns something as base-64, but what? SVG is a vector format whereas PNG is a pixel format, so it's a bit confusing (to me) what you're trying to do here. Sure, you can render a vector image onto a memory bitmap and then save that as a PNG, but why would you?

Sorry. I forgot to add the definition for this method. It takes the link of each image and converts it to base64 and returns it

SVG is xml format which is text.  Images are just embedded in the XML.  SVG can be huge and not all XML libraries can handle huge files.  With Huge XML I like using XmlReader with c# or Powershell.  SVG can multiple layers so you may not want to extract every layer.  Best to open XML with a Text editor like Notepad++ and look at the data before you write any code.
